# Cosine similarity and cosine distance formulas relation

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, cosine-similarity

Can someone explain these two formulas? Do they have any relationship?

````
def _cosine_distance(a, b, data_is_normalized=False):
    if not data_is_normalized:
        a = np.asarray(a) / np.linalg.norm(a, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        b = np.asarray(b) / np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return 1. - np.dot(a, b.T)

def findCosineSimilarity(source_representation, test_representation):
    a = np.matmul(np.transpose(source_representation), test_representation)
    b = np.sum(np.multiply(source_representation, source_representation))
    c = np.sum(np.multiply(test_representation, test_representation))
    return 1 - (a / (np.sqrt(b) * np.sqrt(c)))```
````

Comment: Have you tested if they calculate the same output for the same input? My guess is that it's the same function ([cosine distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity), `1-S_c(A,B)`), but the top approach first calculates the individual fractions, while the bottom approach calculates the fraction last. By the way, as I see it, none of the equations above describe cosine **similarity**, but both describe the cosine **distance**.

Comment: findCosineSimilarity works with 1D array, the other one not. Also, two arrays of shape (2,5) were given as input, _cosine_distance returned (2,2) matrix, findCosineSimilarity- (5,5) matrix. I think there should be relation. Also, I cannot understand np.linalg.norm() function

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment, the cosine distance of two matrices of shape `2 x 5` essentially consists of finding the *pairwise* cosine distance between the *vectors* in each array. Assuming you are working with row vectors (which you should when you use NumPy conventionally), the expected output should consist of `2 * 2 = 4` elements. If you are working with column vectors, then `5 * 5 = 25` elements makes sense.

##### _cosine_distance looks good

The function `_cosine_distance` is correct in naming and implementation generally for all cases where `a in N^{n x l}` and `b in N^{m x l}`.

To use `_cosine_distance` for 1D arrays you can simply add a singleton dimension at axis 0, e.g. `_cosine_distance(a[np.newaxis], b[np.newaxis])`.

##### findCosineSimilarity looks bad

`findCosineSimilarity` is incorrect in naming (it calculates the cosine distance), and the implementation *only* works if you have one dimensional arrays. Using this for anything other than 1D arrays *will fail* as it will compute something that is *incorrect* by the definition of cosine distance. Also, transposing `source_representation` (the left matrix) hints that the function is meant for *column vectors*, which differs from `_cosine_distance`, not that `findCosineSimilarity`  would work for matrices anyways.

It is easy to create a column/row vector agnostic test case by using a `n x n` matrix:

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

If we calculate the pairwise cosine distance for every vector in the matrix we should get all zeros as the vectors are the same.

```py
import numpy as np

def findCosineSimilarity(source_representation, test_representation):
    a = np.matmul(np.transpose(source_representation), test_representation)
    b = np.sum(np.multiply(source_representation, source_representation))
    c = np.sum(np.multiply(test_representation, test_representation))
    return 1 - (a / (np.sqrt(b) * np.sqrt(c)))

def _cosine_distance(a, b, data_is_normalized=False):
    if not data_is_normalized:
        a = np.asarray(a) / np.linalg.norm(a, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        b = np.asarray(b) / np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return 1. - np.dot(a, b.T)

a = np.array([
    [1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1]
])

print(findCosineSimilarity(a,a))
print(_cosine_distance(a, a))
```

Output:

```
[[0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75]
 [0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75]
 [0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75]
 [0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75]]
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

We see that `findCosineSimilarity` fails, and that `_cosine_distance` is correct.